# Python : how to 'concatenate' 2 pd.DataFrame columns ? two columns into one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have trouble with some pandas dataframes.
Its very simple, I have 4 columns, and I want to reshape them in 2...

For 'practical' reasons, I don't want to use 'header names', but I need to use 'index' (for the columns header names).

I have :
 `df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3],'b': [4,5,6],'c': [7,8,9],'d':[10,11,12]})`

I want as a result :
`df_res = pd.DataFrame({'NewName1': [1,2,3,4,5,6],'NewName2': [7,8,9,10,11,12]})`

(in fact `NewName1` doesn't matter, it can stay `a` or whatever the name...)

I tried with for loops, append, concat, but couldn't figured it out...

Any suggestions ?

Thanks for your help !
Bina

Comment: Since they are integers, you could dump it into numpy and `reshape`: ``pd.DataFrame(df.to_numpy().reshape(-1,2, order = 'F'), columns = ['NewName1', 'NewName2'])
``

Comment: Thanks Sammy, although I would have prefered to keep using 'DataFrame' (avoid np), it's working properly.

Comment: You could do ``pd.concat([df.iloc[:, :2].stack().rename('NewName1').droplevel(-1), df.iloc[:, 2:].stack().droplevel(-1).rename('NewName2')], axis = 'columns')`` but that is verbose, unnecessary, and inefficient. Pandas is built significantly on Numpy; there is no reason to avoid it

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the desired columns and create a new `pandas.DataFrame` like so:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3],'b': [4,5,6],'c': [7,8,9],'d':[10,11,12]})

first_col = np.concatenate((df.a.to_numpy(), df.b.to_numpy()))
second_col = np.concatenate((df.c.to_numpy(), df.d.to_numpy()))

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"NewName1": first_col, "NewName2": second_col})

>>> df2
        NewName1  NewName2
    0         1         7
    1         2         8
    2         3         9
    3         4        10
    4         5        11
    5         6        12
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to 'avoid' using 'a' or 'b', but to rather use 'indexes' ?

Comment: Then, see @sammywemy's comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the most elegant solution, but I would isolate the two dataframes and then concatenate them. I needed to rename the column axis so that the four columns could be aligned correctly.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3],'b': [4,5,6],'c': [7,8,9],'d':[10,11,12]})

af = df[['a', 'c']]
bf = df[['b', 'd']]

frames = (
    af.rename({'a': 'NewName1', 'c': 'NewName2'}, axis=1),
    bf.rename({'b': 'NewName1', 'd': 'NewName2'}, axis=1)
)

out = pd.concat(frames)
```

[EDIT] Replying to the comment.

I'm not that familiar with indexing but this might be one solution. You could avoid column names by using `.iloc`. Replace the `af`, and `bf` frames above with these lines.

```py
af = df.iloc[:, ::2]
bf = df.iloc[:, 1::2]
```

Comment: Thanks, but same comment, is there a way to 'avoid' using 'a' or 'b', but to rather use 'indexes' ?